# Клиент/сервер Python

Tags: python

В общем суть вопроса. Мне нужно чтобы у меня все обрабатывалось на моем компьютере(соответственно это сервер), после этого отправлялись клиенту(в моем случае это линукс(дебиан), клиент принимает данные и уже решает что с ними делать и все это должно происходить в режиме реального времени и постоянно, нашел в интернете что-то связанное с этим, это rpyc, по описанию он примерно подходит под то что я хочу реализовать, так вот вопрос, подойдет ли этот rpyc для моих нужд? Или есть что-то еще намного проще?

Comment: Для реализации клиент-сервера я бы на вашем месте использовал requests и flask. Когда-то давно его делал с этим стеком, могу скинуть как пример.

Comment: @SmellyNS тут же нет личных сообщений, куда именно можно написать? Да и в вопросах/ответах не нашел такого

Comment: Если нужно взаимодействие прям в реальном времени - можно использовать вебсокеты. Если не критично - можно клиентом периодически запрашивать данные с сервера, при наличии данных сервер отдает их (просто по протоколу HTTP - например через те же requests на клиенте и flask на сервере).

Comment: Какие-то все сложные методы если честно, может есть что попроще? У меня на компьютере постоянно опрашивается сенсор с кинекта, из него я вытаскиваю координаты по x y z обрабатываю их и говорю что блок управления должен что-то сделать если это подходит под мои условия, потом я хочу запросить с линукса(блока управления) результат обработки который происходит на сервере в режиме реального времени и чтобы блок воспроизвел то что задано на сервере. Попытался все это сделать через сокеты, но подключение между блоком и пк не хочется создаваться, я знаю что явно делаю что-то не так, только не знаю что

Comment: @ВасилийБрагин, если через сокеты не проходит подключение - проверяйте настройки брандмауэра, возможно порт на сервере заблокирован. HTTP и Websockets - это не сложные методы, для всего есть готовые библиотеки, и даже по базовому примеру кода уже можно накропать свои клиент и сервер.

Comment: С помощью сокета подключился, все окей, единственный ньюанс не дает запустить сервер по новой на том же порте, нужно менять порт, не знаю после ребута пк открываются ли они по новой, но может это по другому как-то решить?

Comment: У меня есть 2 цикла в котором постоянно идет опрос датчиков, есть постоянные значения x y z в зависимости от которых должен работать определенный мотор. соответственно в коде выглядит примерно так:
if y > 0: Leds.set_color(Leds.LEFT, Leds.GREEN)
elif y < 0 : Leds.set_color(Leds.RIGHT, Leds.RED)
В данном случае я беру только одну руку и мне нужно чтобы вот этот leds попал на блок управления и выполнил это, каким образом что я должен запрашивать?